# Why can not login LeetCode in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I can login LeetCode using browser，and I get a connect error when I trying to login LeetCode in VS Code.

```
[ERROR] Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 47.99.228.218:443
```

Also, I can access `47.99.228.218` by using ping.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the [ask] link and update your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use third-party login (e.g. GitHub or LinkedIn), please make sure your account has been connected to the thrid-party.

[image]

Simply click **Sign in to LeetCode** in the `LeetCode Explorer` will let you **sign in** with your LeetCode account.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue when I am trying to log in VS code leetcode extension. Then I used another way of leetcode login using VS code i.e. `Leetcode Cookie`. In this method, you need to use your leetcode username and then it will ask for the browser cookie of the leetcode website.

[image]

To copy the cookie you need to go to the browser network tab and grab the first call of `Graphql` endpoint and copy the whole content of the cookie & paste this into VS code login where it's asking for the cookie to enter. I have attached the screenshot below for the cookie info.

[image]

Once you have given the all info it will list all the problems available in leetcode in VS code editor.